# Generating truncated negative binomial distribution in python

Tags: python, probability-distribution

I am trying to generate datasets following truncated negative binomial distribution consisting of numbers such that the number set has a max value.

```
def truncated_Nbinom(n, p, max_value, size):
    import scipy.stats as sct
    temp_size = size
    while True:
        temp_size *= 2
        temp = sct.nbinom.rvs(n, p, size=temp_size)
        truncated = temp[temp <= max_value]
        if len(truncated) >= size:
            return truncated[:size]
```

I am able to get results when the max_value and n are smaller. However when I try with:

```
input_1= truncated_Nbinom(99, 0.3, 99, 5000).tolist()
```

The kernel keeps dying. I tried to change the port of python and raising the recursion limit, but they didn't work. Do you have any ideas to make my code faster?

Comment: What do you mean by "dying"?

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook, while working on the code after some long time the console says "the kernel has died and it will be restarted" before returning the code.

Comment: I suspect you have a potential infinite loop and the doubling of temp_size each time will eat memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. You can compute the probability of `x` being selected under the negative binomial, then normalize the probabilities for `x`s below `max_value` to sum to one. Now, you can simply call `np.random.choice` with appropriate probabilities.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats


def truncated_Nbinom2(n, p, max_value, size):
  support = np.arange(max_value + 1)
  probs = stats.nbinom.pmf(support, n, p)
  probs /= probs.sum()
  return np.random.choice(support, size=size, p=probs)
```

Here is an illustration:

```
arr1 = truncated_Nbinom(9, 0.3, 9, 50000)
arr2 = truncated_Nbinom2(9, 0.3, 9, 50000)

df_counts = pd.DataFrame({
    "version_1": pd.Series(arr1).value_counts(),
    "version_2": pd.Series(arr2).value_counts(),
})
```

[image]